# WorksheetFunction.Countifs 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a complex Excel VBA application and trying to use Countifs function. The problem is it is giving me a Type mismatch error I am unable to point a finger to. It would be too complex to paste the entire code here but I am pasting what I think are the relevant lines of the code

```
Public NumSecTypes As Integer
Public NumSecurities As Integer
.
.
.
Dim i as Integer
Dim AvgPoSSizeCountif As Double
Dim SecType As String
.
.
.
    Sheets("Output").Select

    AvgPoSSizeCountif = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(Cells(i + 1, (17 + 2 * NumSecTypes)), Cells(i + 1, (16 + 2 * NumSecTypes + NumSecurities))), Range(Cells(6, (17 + 2 * NumSecTypes)), Cells(6, (16 + 2 * NumSecTypes + NumSecurities))), SecType, Range(Cells(i + 1, (21 + 2 * NumSecTypes + 2 * NumSecurities)), Cells(i + 1, (20 + 2 * NumSecTypes + 3 * NumSecurities))), ">0")
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? The error is in the "AvgPoSSizeCountif = ..." line

Many thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated. Kindly let me know if you need any other information

Comment: We need more infoirmation such as workbook example. Fo example what is `SecType`, `NumSecurities` etc

Comment: Thanks brettdj. As pointed by Andrew, the syntax was the issue. Please see remarks below. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the CountIfs function should be

```
CountIfs( criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2, ...])
```

It looks like you are missing the criteria that matches Parameter 1. This is what your function looks like below:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(

// Parameter 1
Range(Cells(i + 1, (17 + 2 * NumSecTypes)), Cells(i + 1, (16 + 2 * NumSecTypes + NumSecurities))), 

// Parameter 2
Range(Cells(6, (17 + 2 * NumSecTypes)), Cells(6, (16 + 2 * NumSecTypes + NumSecurities))),

// Parameter 3
SecType, 

// Parameter 4
Range(Cells(i + 1, (21 + 2 * NumSecTypes + 2 * NumSecurities)), Cells(i + 1, (20 + 2 * NumSecTypes + 3 * NumSecurities))), 

// Parameter 5
">0"

)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Silly me. Never occurred to me that this could be the problem. Seems to be working fine ... not getting run time errors. But the calculations are an issue... getting all zeroes :-( Will keep you posted.

Comment: Is there a way to see what a Excel VBA formula is doing. Something like evaluate formula in Excel. The countifs are returning zeros for some reason not known to me

Comment: You can try the VBA debugging menu. In this case it is probably just as easy to just walk through a few examples by hand. Plugging in values for i, NumSecTypes, NumSecurities, and SecType.

Comment: I am using F8 to step through the code. that is how I found out that the problem is with countif returning wrong values. I tried Application.Countifs instead of WorksheetFunction. Still did not work

Comment: Try starting with only one pair of criteria range and criteria and see if it works as expected. If it does, then add another criteria range and criteria pair and check if it still works. I suspect the problem could be that Parameter 1 and Parameter 4 in my code above are using the same columns for the range.

Comment: I found that if I declare ranges and set the above cell ranges to them using Set command, the functions work properly. Thanks Andrew and brettdj for the help.